# SQL: Retrieve Values if different from prior date

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have the following Table:

```
Date_            Value_
2013-07-13       100055
2013-07-14       100055
2013-07-15       120060
2013-07-16       115040
2013-07-17       115040
2013-07-18       130005
```

I would like to return the first value in my results and every change.

Desired output:

```
Date_            Value_
2013-07-13       100055
2013-07-15       120060
2013-07-16       115040
2013-07-18       130005
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for `group by` clause and `min` function

```
select min(Date_) as Date_, Value_
from tab
group by Value_
```

Comment: Thanks! I knew it was easy!